# How to mix scrolling and fixed elements?

Tags: css, wrapper

I'd like to have many elements fixed, but then have the main text block scroll.

Before I start coding, I'd just like some advice on the best way to do this. Should I wrap ALL the fixed elements together, and then inside that, have a relative element for the scrolling part?

Here is what I am trying to do:

[image]

Comment: The div which you want to scroll should have overflow: auto set to it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should create a main wrapper for your page which will have a relative position and that you center horizontally on your page (using `margin: 0 auto;` for example).

Then add inside that wrapper a `<nav>` for your top navigation and set its css position property to `fixed`, and then do the same for the sidebar with a `<aside>`.

Then add inside the wrapper a `<div id="content"></div>` for instance for your content and set its css position property to `relative`. If you want the content of this div to scroll vertically, you can add the following css : `overflow: auto;`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you well, you want your content to change without the page being reloaded & that the content scrolls, but not the rest.

You can :

1. Wrap your content into an `iframe`, so you can change the content without refreshing the whole page with a fixed `height`,
2. Just use a fixed height to your content `div`, and set this :

   ```
   #yourDivId{
       overflow:scroll;
       overflow-y:none;
       height: XXX px;    //Fixed height;
   }
   ```

   *Note : your mouse will have to hover the content to scroll it.*

Comment: wouldn't the iframe have those ugly scroll bars on the side?

Comment: @Claire Yes it would by default. If you don't want some scroll bar on your content container, you should fix every section of your site (sidebar, header...) **but** the content `div`, and apply a correct positioning (absolute). You'll then have the scrollbar on your window's right side as usual.

Answer (score 0):

Well an advice?
Create separately three blocks; for fixed Nav, Fixed sidebar(for category) and scrolled main block(article). It'll be easy to order, I guess.

How many Category will display on the fixed sidebar? if the list heigher than window's screen, some category will be hidden unless you make it 'overflow:auto'. also consider about possibility of user resizing the screen.

Happy Coding !